# Updating deleting and inserting into main table without using cursors?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, insert-update

```
#TEMP

TomID    Value      Name
634     38.000000   LI
634     38.000000   LI
670     38.000000   LI
722     37.240000   LI
723     37.240000   LI
724     37.240000   LI
634     2.000000    RAN
670     2.000000    RAN
722     1.960000    RAN
723     1.960000    RAN
724     1.960000    RAN
634     20.000000   TAU
670     20.000000   TAU
722     19.600000   TAU
723     19.600000   TAU
```

MainTable

```
TomID    Value      Name

166        77         RS
634       38         LI  
723     19.600000   TAU
```

By using the Temp table i want to insert all my rows into main table 
Condition:
if TomID AND Name are qual the the value should be updated in main table.
I dont want to use cursors
can you guys please help me

Comment: What about before insert trigger that compares `TomID` And `Name` and acts accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `MERGE` statement. [Reference](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/28/sql-server-2008-introduction-to-merge-statement-one-statement-for-insert-update-delete/)

I think this will get you what you want:

```
MERGE MainTable AS M
USING (SELECT * FROM #temp) AS T
ON  M.TomID = T.TomID AND M.Name = T.Name
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
   SET M.Value = T.Value
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT(TomId, Value, Name)
    VALUES(T.TomId, T.Value, T.Name);
```

Answer (score 1):

-- `MERGE` statement will help.

```
MERGE MainTable AS target
    USING (SELECT TomID, Value,Name from #temp) AS source (TomID, Value, Name)
    ON (target.TomID = source.TomID and target.Name = source.Name)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET Value = source.Value
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN   
        INSERT (TomID, Name,Value)
        VALUES (source.TomID, source.Name,source.Value);
```

[MERGE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)